# roUrlTransfer function not working in BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am creating my own channel for Roku. I need to get the streams of my videos and images from a JSON file on a server.

Code in my SceneGraph .xml file:

```
<![CDATA[sub init()
 data = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
 data.SetUrl(url)
 data.AsyncGetToString()
end sub]]>
```

This code is working fine in a `Task` node and the `main.brs` file, but in my .xml file it generates this error: **"invalid BrightScript Component or interface reference"**.

Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 8):

Within SceneGraph applications, you are only allowed to use roUrlTransfer in Task nodes, to ensure all network traffic is handled asynchronously. Could that be the source of the problem? Or are you referring to the XML of your Task node?

The full list of limitations on how you can use BrightScript in SceneGraph can be found in the Roku SDK documentation, specifically the section [BrightScript Support](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Support).

Comment: Thank you  so much for reply and also you are right.

Answer (score 0):

This function only uses in Task nodes within Scene Graph Applications.
[BrightScript Support](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Support)

[Task Node](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Task#Task-Description)